# URL safe characters RegEx that will allow UTF-8 accents!

Tags: regex, url, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a RegEx pattern to use in a `rereplace()` function that will keep URL safe characters, but include UTF-8 characters with accents. For example:  `ç` and `ã`.

Something like: `url = rereplace(local.url, "pattern")` etc. I prefer a ColdFusion only solution, but I'm open to using Java too since it's so easy to integrate with CF.

My URL pattern will look like: `/posts/[postId]/[title-with-accents-like-ç-and-ã]`

Comment: @Chris Lutz, I'm using ColdFusion, sorry, I thought it's just a matter of using a pattern, so I did not include the language.

Comment: @Chris, I guess it could also be java based!

Comment: Different languages have different regex flavors, and UTF handling is likely one of the more language-dependent parts. Alas, I cannot help you with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by matching alpha numeric characters using `\w`.

`rereplace(string, "[^\w]", "", "all")`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548815/how-do-i-match-latin-unicode-characters-in-coldfusion-or-java-regex/6548859#6548859) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you are using. Perl has some utf8 matching, see for example Tatsuhiko Miyagawa's [URI::Find::UTF8](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aFind%3a%3aUTF8)

Comment: Ok now that I see that you are using ColdFusion, I don't know that this will help anymore. Perl's Regex engine is very advanced (Read: not compatible with lesser engines) and the newest version (5.14.0) has improved unicode regexes even further. If ColdFusion's matching cannot help you perhaps Perl can.