# How do I match latin unicode characters in ColdFusion or Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion

I'm looking for a ColdFusion or Java regex (to use in a replace function) that will only match numbers [0-9], letters [a-z], but include none ASCII **Portuguese** letters (unicode latin, like `ç` and `ã`).

Some like this:

```
str = reReplaceNoCase(str, "match none number/letter but keep unicode latin chars", "", "ALL");
```

`Input string: "informação 123 ?:#$%"`
`Desired outcome: "informação 123"`

I know I can match letters and numbers with `[a-z][0-9]`, but this doesn't match letters such as `ç` and `ã`.

Comment: Are you looking to replace all characters that aren't a-z, or just those two?  If you are looking to replace all, i think you woulod be better pulling the stuff you want to keep out of your string and build a new one.

Comment: @Limey, I edited my question to show the desired outcome. I'm looking to keep only [a-z][0-9] and Portuguse characters, which I understand are latin Unicode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try alphanumeric character class: `\w`, it should match letters, digits, and underscores.

Also you can use special named class `\p{L}` (I don't know, does Java RegEx parser support it).
So in C# your task can be done using following code:

```
var input = "informação 123 ?:#$%";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\p{L}\s0-9]", string.Empty);
```

Regex `[^\p{L}\s0-9]` means: any character **not** in this class (all letters, white space, digits). Thereby it matches in your example `?:#$%` and we can replace these characters with empty string.

Comment: @polishchuck, that would remove the `ç` and `ã`, which I want to keep.

Comment: @Mohamad, `\w` will match `ç` and `ã`

Comment: @polishchuck, you're right, sorry, the online tester I used was PHP, I think!

Comment: @polishchuck, how would I keep spaces? I'm doing this now, `reReplace(input, "[^\w]", "", "ALL");` but that removes spaces, and I need those :/

Comment: @Mohamad, add space inside `[]`, e.g.: `[^\w ]` or using special class `[^\w\s]`